# Show User name instead of id in Rails partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know there must be a very simple solution, but I just can't figure out how.

Inside the auction show view, I am displaying a list off all bids with the regarding bidder (=User who have placed the bid). When placing a new bid, the user_id is successfully saved within the bid table.

I want to display the bidders name instead of his ID. (with @bidder = User.find(@bid.user_id))

**bids_controller.rb:**

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController
  # Create new bid
  def create
    # find Auction related to new Bid
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @bid = @auction.bids.create(bid_params)
    @bid.user_id = current_user.id
    # Find the bidder within User Table
    @bidder = User.find(@bid.user_id)
    @bid.save
    redirect_to auction_path(@auction), :notice => "Bid placed"
  end
```

**Bids Partial view: views\bids\ _bid.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Bidder:</strong>
  <%= @bidder.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Bid-Amount:</strong>
  <%= bid.amount %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Bid', [bid.auction, bid],
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

The whole thing is displayed within the Auctions Show View:

**views\auctions\show.html.erb**

```
<h2>Bids</h2>
<%= render @auction.bids %>
<h2>Place a Bid:</h2>
<%= render 'bids/form' %>
<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @auction.comments %>
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

The Error:

> NoMethodError in Auctions#show Showing
>   C:/Users/santa/Documents/rails/app/views/bids/_bid.html.erb
>   where line #3 raised:
>
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass Extracted source (around line
>
> ## 3): 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> ```
>          <p>
> <strong>Bidder:</strong>
> <%= @bidder.name %>   </p>
>  <p>
> ```
>
> Trace of template inclusion: app/views/auctions/show.html.erb

name exists in Users table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<%= @bidder.name %>` try add `<%= bid.user.name %>`. If `user_id` saving properly in `bid` table then clearly there is `has_many` and `belongs_to` association there.

Just replace `<%= @bidder.name %>` to `<%= bid.user.name %>`

Comment: Thank you, thats it! (Can't believe I spent 4 hours trying...) I'll accept in 8 min.

Comment: Ok. It happened sometime :)